# Sending concurrent emails with Nodemailer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp

I'm trying to send verification emails when someone fills a form on my website and I'm achieving this using nodemailer.

And my node.js code looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{

  var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", 
  secureConnection: false, 
  port: 587,
  tls: {
     ciphers:'SSLv3',
     rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
  auth: {
      user: 'generic-email@outlook.com',
      pass: 'generic-password'
  }
  });
  
  var mailOptions = {
  from: 'generic-email@outlook.com',
  to: req.body.email_name, 
  subject: 'testing <No-Reply Email>', 
  text: 'testing', 
  html: `<div>testing</div>`
  };

   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, await function(error, info){
   if(error)
   {
     console.log(error);
     return res.json({stat:'not good'});
   }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    return res.json({stat:'all good'});
  });
});


app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('Listening at Port 3000...');
 });
```

and although it works fine I suspect that if multiple people make the same request then it will give `response: '421 concurrent connection limit in Avast exceeded(pass:0, processes:node.exe[46])`' ERROR.

I got this error when I tried to loop through the code and send 300 Emails to myself to test the limit of per day email limit

How do I avoid this error when the site is live?

So far I've come up with 2 possible explanations:

1. I could loop the code such that is keeps trying to send an email until it gets an opportunity
2. I will have to use some other service other than outlook

What can I do in this situation? Am I taking the right approach? Should I use some other Email API service? I'm fairly new to all this SMTP stuff.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is you are creating a new connection for each request, just do

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", 
  secureConnection: false, 
  port: 587,
  tls: {
     ciphers:'SSLv3',
     rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
  auth: {
      user: 'generic-email@outlook.com',
      pass: 'generic-password'
  }
});

const app=express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'generic-email@outlook.com',
    to: req.body.email_name, 
    subject: 'testing <No-Reply Email>', 
    text: 'testing', 
    html: `<div>testing</div>`
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, await function(error, info){
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.json({stat:'not good'});
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    return res.json({stat:'all good'});
  });
});
```

Comment: works like a charm but can it accommodate multiple requests?
like if multiple people start using the site will each request be sent simultaneously or will it queue and send one at a time?

Comment: It will send simultaneously

Comment: how many concurrent connections can the outlook email handle? and how do I handle if too many connections are made at once?

Comment: Not sure how many it can handle, but if you are getting too many connections just add `pool: true,maxConnections: someNumber` to the `createTransport` config

Comment: does that make the additional connections wait or are they forgotten?

Comment: "If pooling is used then Nodemailer keeps a fixed amount of connections open and sends the next message once a connection becomes available." https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/